# How to programatically distinguish between directories and files in Azure File Share?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

I have a piece of code like if

```
        // last path segement can be like "binaries.x86" since
        // directories can have `.` characters in them
        if ((lastItemInPath = cloudFileDirectory.GetFileReference(lastPathSegment)) != null)
        {
            // the last path segment is a file
            return lastItemInPath;
        }
        else if ((lastItemInPath = cloudFileDirectory.GetDirectoryReference(lastPathSegment)) != null)
        {
            // the last path segment is a directory
            return lastItemInPath;
        }
```

which I figured out is wrong because the first `if` returns true even if `lastPathSegment` is truly a directory. Any idea how I can accurately distinguish?

Comment: You can refer to answer from rk. and my comment. Please note that GetFileReference doesn't really trigger any web request to storage service since it just creates an object on client side, that's the reason why your code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try this 

CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Azure Storage Connection String")); 
CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient(); 
CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference("File Share Name"); 

 IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().ListFilesAndDirectories(); 
 foreach (var fileTemp in fileList)  
 { 
    switch (fileTemp.GetType().Name) 
     { 
         case "CloudFile": 
             //Write your logic here 
             break; 
         case "CloudFileDirectory": 
             //Write your logic here 
             break; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can actually use "fileTemp is CloudFile" to avoid string comparison.